# How to get url in which am sending post request using hook

Tags: codeigniter

I have one HTML table in which the last column is edit(button).
if the user clicks on edit then one popup is open and allow to user modify details of that particular row.

I am using *post_controller_constructor* hook in which I need url on which my data are going to post.

Here Am using popup so $this->CI->url is showing of grid/table url. But I need url on which am data is posting.

Would it possible anyway to get this url.

Why this needs: I have one large system in which multiple places has been defined in which the same operations are doing but different different params. So am trying to create add-ons. If you install my addon then my hook will check for your requests dynamically and make it work that way. So your core functionality will not touch by my addons. It will work independently.

Comment: ask yourself if you really need a hook? 99% of the time the answer is no. that being said, it would be helpful to see your code to understand what you are trying to do better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I really need to hook so have posted this question.

Comment: you haven't explained why and what you mean by the "url on which data is posting" (the form url? shouldn't you know that already?)

Comment: Let me explain why in my question to clearout your doubts. Nope, Am not knowing which are the form action .

Comment: if you don't know the form post url then how can you expect to submit a form? this is strange logic.

Comment: Thanks for your great support. I got it somehow answer myself using $this->CI->url->url_string.